# PHP variable with line spacing in conditional statement

Tags: php, variables, conditional-statements

***NOTE**
I found that the problem was trying to enter a space/line break in the email variable used for the "From" header value (*duh*). This of course can't work. So instead I appended the values to the message body. See correct code bellow.

```
<?php

$send_to = "[MY@EMAIL.COM]";
$send_subject = "contact form from website";

$f_name = cleanupentries($_POST["namn"]);
$f_message = cleanupentries($_POST["meddelande"]);
$from_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$from_browser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

function cleanupentries($entry) {
    $entry = trim($entry);
    $entry = stripslashes($entry);
    $entry = htmlspecialchars($entry);

    return $entry;
}

$message = $f_message . "\n\n" . $f_name . "can be reached on:\n";

if(($_POST["epost"]) == "epost" || ($_POST["epost"]) == ""){
    $f_email =  $send_to;
    $f_email_check = "";

    }else{
    $f_email_check = cleanupentries($_POST["epost"]);
    $f_email = $f_email_check;
    $message .= $f_email_check;
    $message .= "\n";
}

if(($_POST["telefon"]) == "telefon" || ($_POST["telefon"]) == ""){
    $f_phone_check = "";

    }else{
    $f_phone_check = cleanupentries($_POST["telefon"]);
    $message .= $f_phone_check;
    $message .= "\n";
}

$message .= "\nTechnical info:\n" . $from_ip . "," . $from_browser;

$headers = "From: " . $f_email . "\r\n" .
    "Reply-To: " . $f_email . "\r\n" .
    "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();

if (!$f_email) {
    echo '<p>No email.</p><br /><p>< <a style="text-decoration: none; color: blue;" href="/" target="_self">Pleas try again</a></p>';
    exit;
}else if (!$f_name){
    echo '<p>No name.</p><br /><p>< <a style="text-decoration: none; color: blue;" href="/" target="_self">Pleas try again</a></p>';
    exit;
}else{
    if (filter_var($f_email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        mail($send_to, $send_subject, $message, $headers);
        echo "true";
    }else{
        echo '<p>Invalid email.</p><br /><p>< <a style="text-decoration: none; color: blue;" href="/" target="_self">Pleas try again</a></p>';
        exit;
    }
}
?>
```

**-------------- ORIGINAL POST --------------**

I've been trying back and forth to get this to work, but no matter what I do I can't get it to work. What am I doing wrong here (see code bellow)?

What I'm trying to do is to add a line space (\n) if the else is true, otherwise it should display nothing. The displaying nothing part works just fine, its the adding of a line space that I can't get to work.
If I add `$f_email_check .= "\n";` the email doesn't get sent.

I've also tried `$f_email_check = cleanupentries($_POST["epost"]."\n");` same problem.

And same thing with `$f_email_check = cleanupentries($_POST["epost"])."\n";`.

If I completely remove the \n part the mail sends just fine. However, since the email and phone (that comes after the email) is on the same line with no space in the message body the email and phone go a as one long string. I know I can enter a \n or space in the message body, but then there will be a line space even if the email is empty in the message body.

What I'm trying to achieve is, if there is no email given, present nothing (in regards to email), if both phone AND email are given, put email on one line then on the next line show phone...

This is the full code I'm using

```
<?php

$send_to = "[MY@EMAIL.COM]";
$send_subject = "webpage contactform";

$f_name = cleanupentries($_POST["namn"]);

if(($_POST["epost"]) == "epost" || ($_POST["epost"]) == ""){
    $f_email =  $send_to;
    $f_email_check = "";

    }else{
    $f_email_check = cleanupentries($_POST["epost"]."\n");
    $f_email_check .= "";
    $f_email = $f_email_check;
}

if(($_POST["telefon"]) == "telefon" || ($_POST["telefon"]) == ""){
    $f_phone_check = "";

    }else{
    $f_phone_check = cleanupentries($_POST["telefon"]);
}

$f_message = cleanupentries($_POST["meddelande"]);
$from_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$from_browser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

function cleanupentries($entry) {
    $entry = trim($entry);
    $entry = stripslashes($entry);
    $entry = htmlspecialchars($entry);

    return $entry;
}

$message = $f_message . "\n\n" . $f_name . "can be reached on\n" . $f_email_check . "" . $f_phone_check . "\n\nTechnical info:\n" . $from_ip . "," . $from_browser;

$headers = "From: " . $f_email . "\r\n" .
    "Reply-To: " . $f_email . "\r\n" .
    "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();

if (!$f_email) {
    echo '<p>No email.</p><br /><p>< <a style="text-decoration: none; color: blue;" href="/" target="_self">Please try again</a></p>';
    exit;
}else if (!$f_name){
    echo '<p>No name.</p><br /><p>< <a style="text-decoration: none; color: blue;" href="/" target="_self">Please try again</a></p>';
    exit;
}else{
    if (filter_var($f_email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        mail($send_to, $send_subject, $message, $headers);
        echo "true";
    }else{
        echo '<p>Invalid email.</p><br /><p>< <a style="text-decoration: none; color: blue;" href="/" target="_self">Please try again</a></p>';
        exit;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: doesn't get sent how? `mail()` returns boolean false? your mail server rejects the mail? the mail goes into spam on the receiving end?

Comment: Upvote for editing code for those whoe stumble upon this question! (and a very good and clear question) :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be sending an HTML formatted e-mail. HTML ignores whitespace.

Use `<br>` to get a newline. You can also put `nl2br()` in your `cleanupentries` function but that might not be what you intended.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I've already tried both of these in my initial post  :P  I can't get ANYTHING to work  :(  could you please provide me with an example of how I should append the <br> to the else statements content? I've tried nl2br, <br />, <br>, \n... I just can't get any of them to work. Its driving me crazy haha  :)  I'm sure it's just a question of a space, quotes or a dot somewhere, but I can't see where

Comment: That doesn't make any sense to me. Maybe your email client is just bad? Either send your mail as plain text and `\n` will work, and `<br>` will work for HTML. Some mail clients will _fallback_ to the plain text variant if they don't like HTML, make sure you've correctly set the plain text part of the mail as well (replace `<br>` by `\n` and `strip_tags` will cover most of it).

Comment: ok, but shouldn't this work then? `$f_email_check = cleanupentries($_POST["epost"]."<br>");` cause everything else works just fine. I can't see that the email client is the problem. Most likely I've missed something in writing the else statement no?  :)

Comment: `cleanupentries` will htmlencode your HTML (that's how you wrote it!). Don't put HTML into it that you want to have effected. `$f_email_check = cleanupentries($_POST["epost"]) . "<br>";` Could work.

Comment: Nope, `$f_email_check = cleanupentries($_POST["epost"]) . "<br>";` doesn't work either :(  tried that one before ;)  Thats what I'm saying, something is strange... I've also tried removing the cleanupentries function, to see if it was causing problems, but that didn't help either.

Comment: Think I just realized something! Since the $f_email_check is used to define the $f_email (which in turn is used as "From" header) it can't contain a space or line break... thats probably whats making it not go thru.

Comment: Yep, that was it. I'll revise my initial entry (for others who stumble upon this question).

Answer (score 0):

Reading the manual for filter_var (the comments) with FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL isn't the best option to use (http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php).

Instead of:

```
if (filter_var($f_email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    mail($send_to, $send_subject, $message, $headers);
    echo "true";
}else{
    echo '<p>Invalid email.</p><br /><p>< <a style="text-decoration: none; color: blue;" href="/" target="_self">Please try again</a></p>';
    exit;
}
```

I would try something like:

```
try {
    mail($send_to, $send_subject, $message, $headers);
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    throw new Exception($e->__toString();
}
```

OR

```
$mail =   mail($send_to, $send_subject, $message, $headers);

//check result of $mail.
//...
```

Comment: I though it was hard to tell the actual problem even if your question was very good and clear! :-) It was hard to tell why the mail didn't get sent. It could have been that the email didn't validate for some reason or it could have been something with the mailserver. I did not think it had anything to do with the mailserver (I didn't sound like it) This answer was based on a qualifed guess. Based on the accepted answer here, I wasn't so far from the truth :-)